# FIFO sometimes requires two writes to satisfy read

Tags: linux, fifo

I found some baffling behavior on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

In one terminal, I'd like to write a private key to a FIFO.

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/fifo
$ chmod o-rwx /tmp/fifo
$ chmod g-rwx /tmp/fifo
$ cat id_rsa > /tmp/fifo
```

In another terminal, I'd like to read that FIFO in order to obtain the contents of the key.

```
$ ssh -i /tmp/fifo -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <<user@address>>
```

I would expect that the write in the first terminal would block until the read occurs in the second terminal, at which point both would be released. And this does happen most of the time.

Unfortunately, there are times when it takes two writes (the cat operation) to make the read succeed; the read will release the first write, but the read itself will not be released until another write occurs.

Has anyone observed this phenomenon before? Any information would be most appreciated.

Comment: Is your privatekey file encrypted (aka 'protected') by a password? If so, `ssh` opens/reads /closes it twice; for a regular file this works fine, but for a fifo not so much.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, that is a very interesting idea. i have done nothing to encrypt this password (standard application of ssh_keygen). how would i know if this is the case? i will add that the read works for one user but not another. anyway, thank you for responding.

Comment: Did you give a nonempty password when prompted? Are different users using the same keyfile(s)? See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/200935/how-do-i-determine-if-an-existing-ssh-private-key-is-secure